# JavaScript Dice Game is returning 0

Tags: javascript

There are many posts on Stack Overflow about JavaScript dice games, but I could not find one that answers my question.  This code is adapted from CodeCademy:

```
function rollSingleDice() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1);
}

function rollDice(player) {
var score = 0;
var roll1; var roll2;
var playerScore = player.getScore();
    do {
        roll1 = rollSingleDice();
        roll2 = rollSingleDice();
    } while (roll1 === roll2);

    score = roll1 + roll2;
    player.addToScore(score);

    if (roll1 === roll2) {
        console.log(player.name + "'s current score is: " +
        playerScore);
    } else {
        console.log(player.name + "'s current score is: " +
        playerScore);
    }
   // return score;
}


function Player(name) {
  this.name = name;
  var score = 0; // this is a private attribute
  this.addToScore = function(points) {
    score = score + points;
  };
  this.getScore = function() {
    return score;
  };
}

var player1 = new Player("Bobby");
rollDice(player1);
```

I have modified the `do ... while` loop several times and the only output I get is the following:

`Bobby's current score is: 0`

Could someone please point me in the right direction?  Thank you.

Comment: you should call getScore when you want access it. playerScore is not pointing to the score propertie of player, so your console .log display the last score of the player. could try calling rollDice twice.

Comment: What do you mean by "adapted"?  I see at least one logical flaw in this code...

Comment: Why are you disallowing rolls where the dice come up equal? Is that for some particular game rule?

Comment: When the player rolls doubles the game is over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before logging a player's score, be sure to update it

```
 function rollDice(player) {
 var score = 0;
 var roll1; var roll2;
 var playerScore = player.getScore();
 do {
    roll1 = rollSingleDice();
    roll2 = rollSingleDice();
} while (roll1 === roll2);

score = roll1 + roll2;
player.addToScore(score);

//Add this line in
playerScore = player.getScore();

if (roll1 === roll2) {
    console.log(player.name + "'s current score is: " +
    playerScore);
} else {
    console.log(player.name + "'s current score is: " +
    playerScore);
}
// return score;
}
```

Happy coding! Leave a comment if you have any questions.

Comment: I see now, thank you.  Little things in JavaScript tend to trip me up as I'm getting used to the syntax.

Comment: Sure thing. It can be kind of tricky and it's easy to overlook things. Let us know how finishing the program goes.

Comment: Actually, would you mind taking a look at this gist?  In the comments section I added what they want me to add next.  The part I'm confused about is how the variable snakeEyes will "know" when true is returned. https://gist.github.com/estebanrules/09640735173f8a2893d4

Comment: definitely, I suspect you will need a boolean variable. I will update with some help when I can

Comment: I figured it out.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You fetch the value of the player's score and save it in the "playerScore" variable. However, you don't update that value afterwards, so when you hit the `console.log()` statement later it still has its original value. Change the `console.log` call so that it logs the result of calling `.getScore()` on the player.

```
    console.log(player.name + "'s current score is: " + player.getScore());
```